# Pronunciation of 'educate'

Tags: pronunciation

In India, this word is quite frequently pronounced as *e-JU-cate* (with a J-sound). In the dictionaries I have referred to, the pronunciation is the predictable *e-dyu-cate*. Is the Indian pronunciation common worldwide? Is there any reason for the shift from the dictionaries? Did some look up the phonetic representation, find *ɛdjʊˌkeɪt*, but mistook this 'j' for 'Y'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

British English is the same: most native speakers do not distinguish clearly between "dyu" and "ju".

Comment: Ditto in America.

Comment: It depends on who is hearing. In voice circles, everyone notices that difference.

Answer (score 3):

In America, it's /'ɛdʒəket/, with secondary stress on the last syllable, and primary stress on the **first** syllable. The second syllable is always reduced to shwa /ə/. Some people, sometimes, when they're trying to appear (what they consider) formal and/or prim, might say /'ɛdjʊket/, with secondary stress on both of the last two syllables, but the main stress is always on the first syllable. Americans in general wouldn't notice the difference between /dj/ and /dʒ/ anyway; but the stress difference they would notice immediately.

What you give as the Indian pronunciation, if I read you correctly, might be something like 
/ɛ'dʒʊket/, with primary stress on the second syllable. Many Americans would not understand this pronunciation, or might take a second to recognize it in speech. Of course in writing  there is no problem, isn't it?

Comment: I only disagree with one detail: AmE speakers would immediately notice how out of the ordinary /dj/ was. AmE speakers for the most part only use and expect the affricate. To them it's roughly the difference between 'edge uh kate' and 'ed you kate', very noticeable.

Comment: Quite noticeable. But not always noticed because it's not picked up by many native speakers' broadly-tuned bandpass filters. People vary a **lot** in terms of what they expect to experience, and how much they notice when reality doesn't meet their expectations.